# Issues with making it so the program checks the first or last number to see if it equals the number

Tags: python

Having issues with making it so the program checks the first or last number to see if it equals the number.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 6]

if 6 in list1:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: What are the issues you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
check_val = 6

if list1[0] == check_val or list1[-1] == check_val:
    print("Yes")
else:
  print("No")
```